# React callback with debounce: Child component isn't returning callback to Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash, debouncing

I want to include the `debounce`  function when the button is pressed.

I've written a `debounce` function in `ChildComponent`. It works in `ChildComponent` but I'm not getting the callback in `ParentComponent`.

**Parent:**

```
<MyButton onPress={() => alert("My Button clicked")} />
```

**Child:**

```
const MyButton = props => {
  const {title = 'Enter', style = {}, textStyle = {}, onPress} = props;
  const delayedOnPress = useCallback(
    debounce(() => {
      console.log(onPress);
      return onPress;
    }, 500),
    [],
  );

  const onPressed = () => {
    return delayedOnPress();
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressed} style={[styles.button, style]}>
      <Text style={[styles.text, textStyle]}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Can anyone update me What I was doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notice points:

- Use an arrow function inside `useCallback`.
- No need to return anything inside `debounce` and handler function.

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { TouchableOpacity, Text } from "react-native";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

const debounceAction = debounce(e => {
  console.log(e);   // "My Button clicked"
  alert(e);         // "My Button clicked"
}, 500);

const MyButton = props => {
  const { onPress } = props;
  const delayedOnPress = useCallback(e => debounceAction(e), []);
  const onPressed = () => {
    delayedOnPress(onPress);
  };
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressed}>
      <Text>Button</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyButton onPress="My Button clicked" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

#### Update

If we want to pass a customized function from the parent as a prop:

```
const debounceAction = debounce(e => {
  e();       // customized function been passed
}, 500);

...

export default function App() {
  const customizedFunction = () => { // customized function
    alert("test");
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyButton onPress={customizedFunction} />  // notice no `()` here
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit hardcore-mestorf-eucn1]

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to handle some actions on `ParentComponent`'s props `onPress`. Here you're passing as a string. But I'm expecting a function. How do I do that?

Comment: @DroidLearner Updated

Comment: Thanks. So, here in your updated post, the arrow function has been moved from `ParentComponent` to `ChildComponent` and hence the arrow function is not required anymore on `ParentComponent`??

Comment: Do you have any articles or sources to learn more about the react methods?  It's so confusing when to use () and when not to use () and when to use arrow function  in `<MyButton onPress={customizedFunction} />`

Comment: @DroidLearner If you want to call a function immediately in-place, add `()`, if you want to pass it as a prop (same with string), you don't need `()`. And the react official document is quite specific in those place, it may help. Finally, since the question has been solved, upvote and accept would be appreciated.

Comment: I've accepted the answer. So across the app, I've used arrow function in `ParentComponent` now this has to be replaced in all files because of the `debounce` implementation. Is there any better way to modify it in `ChildComponent` itself?

Comment: @DroidLearner Not sure about your current issue's condition, perhaps write a new post with specific details is a good idea, I would like to have a try at that moment if you don't mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210713/discussion-between-droidlearner-and-keikai).